# Does elementaryOS have updating support? (can i update from one version to another?)

Tags: updates

Can i update from 6.1 to 7 Without any reinstalling when it will be released?

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't. So if you are going from OS5 to 6 then you will need to save your data as kit will be wiped by the new install.